# ssis lookup transformation where source and destination data is huge

Tags: t-sql

I am making updates with source data to destination table.
Source file is excel and destination is sql server table.
In source file I do have one particular project related data where as in destination table i do have several projects. Data contains millions of rows in each project. So the source and destination size is very much.

I am using lookup transformation to compare the data and do the updations accordingly. The problem is it is taking much time to load the entire data in lookup cache as the destination table size is very much. so is there any way of loading the data of only the projects of source file like (select * from table where projectid=sourcetable.projectid)

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: A way to do this would be to create a Script Task and SqlBulkCopy in SSIS to pull into a table first. Then using an inner join, you can easily update the columns for matching projectId

Answer (score 0):

Load your excel data into a staging table and then run your required update via SQL scripts using the staging and destination table.  Running your data transformations will almost always be faster and more efficient as SQL queries between tables on the same server, compared with inside the SSIS data flow.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with Cache Connection Manager. Loaded the Lookup data into Cache File before using the lookup transformation. Later in Lookup Transformation I used this Cache Connection Manager instead of OLEDB Connection Manager.

Another Alternative is using Full Cache and get the table data using parameters instead of reading the whole table data using expressions in DFT.